# Accelerate MySQL import - trigger execution process

Tags: mysql, trigger, import

I'm Fairly new to Database administration. Currently I have to resolve the following situation. I have a 256MB dump file from a MySQL InnoDB table (aproximately 3 million records) that I have to load to a database.

The problem is that for every record in the dump, the database has to run a series of triggers to reconstruct data from a specific table. I can illustrate the process like this:

`dump.record (inserts) => schema.table_a =>{fires_trigger_a} (inserts)=> schema.table_b =>{fires_trigger_b} (inserts)=> ... {fires_trigger_x}(inserts)=> schema.table_final`

I have already tried 3 approaches:

1. Import dump directly to initial table with all triggers in enabled state. This approach made the insertion of the records extremely fast, but didn't fire any triggers. (I suppose the reason behind this is the `LOCK TABLE WRITE` statement inside the dump and/or the `DROP TABLE - CREATE TABLE` statement at the beginning of aforementioned dump)
2. Import edited dump with `LOCK TABLE WRITE` and `DROP TABLE - CREATE TABLE` statements deleted, leaving only `INSERT INTO` statements inside the dump. (This approach fired the triggers as intended but made the data import extremely slow, and the database unusable after cancel and only uploading ~2% of all the records in 30 minutes.)
3. Import txt file created with `mysqldump` that only contains data separated by tab. (After 15 minutes the process was aborted and the initial table didn't get any records.)

None of the aforementioned approaches was successful in the sense that, this import is the first of several, and that currently I can't leave the server running the import for an extended period of time. I'm thinking that maybe there is a way of configuring the MySQL community server installation that I'm currently using to optimize the process, but as I said before I'm just learning.

Thank you for your time, and excuses beforehand for any misspelled word or grammatical errors.

Comment: The *general* idea of `mysqldump` is that the file contains all the tables as they already need to be... so, just as a sanity check, does the database where the dump originated not have these other tables, already populated by the triggers?  Also, are you restoring this into a server that is currently handling other live workloads?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thank you for your response. Indeed the database from which the dump was created contains all the tables and triggers needed for the operation, but as the time went by this original database made mysql crash, so it was necessary to create events for cleanning all tables except the first. The purpose of all the excersice is recreate a huge ammount of data generated in one table after all the triggers fire. Analogically, the new server is an exact copy of the live database without any data and in a close enviroment, no entries are inserted in this database other than the dump.

Answer (score 0):

For loading a large table(s), I would

1. Load the data (`LOAD DATA` or pull in a dump) into a table -- but with no Triggers or Foreign Keys, at least no enabled.
2. Execute queries to perform the transformations desired.  This may include modifying other table, etc.  But this would do it en masse, not one row at a time, hence much faster
3. Then think about Triggers/FKs, etc for future rows that are inserted individually (or in small groups).

"Normalization" is a common task for a big load.  It can be done in 2 statements much faster than 3 million trigger calls:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO norm
    SELECT DISTINCT name FROM loaded_table;
UPDATE loaded_table JOIN norm USING(name)
    SET loaded_table.id = norm.id;
```

That particular example is given in more detail [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization).

Comment: I'll give this a try. Will be updating soon